# phpmyadmin one event two actions

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin

I have an event in phpmyadmin using the console, I wish to add how many rows have been updated/inserted etc using rowcount().

Here is the query

```
REPLACE INTO `request_summary`

SELECT DATE(`Resolution_Date_Time`) as 'TicketDate',
COUNT(`Ticket_Number`) as 'TicketsClosed',
SUM(Case WHEN `SLA_Met` ='No' then 1 else 0 END) as 'FailedSLA',
SUM(Case WHEN `Call_Detail` = 'REQ-IDM-JOINER' then 1 else 0 END) as 'Joiners',
SUM(Case WHEN `Call_Detail` = 'REQ-IDM-LEAVER' then 1 else 0 END) as 'Leavers',
SUM(Case WHEN `ReOpened` = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 END) as 'Reopened'  

FROM  `ticket_data`

WHERE `Resolving_Group` LIKE 'MCO-TechServ%'
and date(`Resolution_Date_Time`) > '2015-01-01'
and `Call_Type` = 'Request'
and (`Logged_Via` = 'RequestIT' or `Logged_Via` = 'IDM')
and `Call_Detail` NOT LIKE '%REQ-UA%'
and `Call_Detail` NOT LIKE '%RQ-UA%'
and `Resolution_Code` != 'REQUEST REJECTED'
Group by Date(`Resolution_Date_Time`);

INSERT INTO `import_log` (`Action`, `Records inserted`)
VALUES ('RequestSummary', ROW_COUNT());
```

When I run it as a query from the SQL page on phpmyadmin console, it runs fine and populates the import_log table. However when I try to add this as a schedueled Event it errors with

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `import_log` (`Action`, `Records
>   inserted`) VALUES ('RequestSummary'' at line 24

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should paste the SQL you use to define the event. Most likely you didn't change the delimiter to something else than `;`